# Programmatically find when the ASP.NET worker process and app domain last started?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, appdomain, worker-process

In ASP.NET:

1. How can I tell when the ASP.NET worker process last restarted?
2. In ASP.NET, how can I tell when the app domain last recycled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the worker process, you can programmatically read **Process -> Elapsed Time** from the corresponding perf. counter  (1) or directly from the **System.Diagnostics.Process** namespace; for the **AppDomain**, you can set an application-level variable at start-up to serve as your baseline and measure against that manually.

Scott Mitchell actually has a couple of good posts on this that are still relevant 8 years later, believe it or not (2). Running on Cassini (Vista, VS 2008), I'm seeing an accurate system up-time with:

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount)
```

...and accurate Process/AppDomain up-times with these:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("WebDev.WebServer"))
{
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now.Subtract(p.StartTime).ToString() + "<br/>");
}

Response.Write(DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)Application["StartTime"]).ToString());
```

I'm also able to obtain the correct **PerfomanceCounter**, but can't seem to read the correct value (always zero, under my setup):

```
Response.Write(new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Elapsed Time", "WebDev.WebServer").NextValue() + "<br/>");
```

Scott's articles are definitely worth a read - there's a wealth of info in **ProcessInfo** and **ProcessModelInfo** (eg. **ProcessModelInfo.GetHistory**), but unfortunately it's not available on Cassini:

> Process metrics are available only
> when the ASP.NET process model is
> enabled.  When running on versions of
> IIS 6 or newer in worker process
> isolation mode, this feature is not
> supported.

**UPDATE:**
great explanation of how to read the counter correctly to avoid the zero on **NextValue()**: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151126015931/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bclteam/archive/2006/06/02/618156.aspx)

HTH

(1) https://serverfault.com/questions/90927/lifetime-of-iis-worker-process-or-appdomai

(2) https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113638/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041002-1.aspx