# Cache expires before it supposed to

Tags: asp.net, caching

Can someone help me here? I have following code to store and revieve catch, however, it doesn't work. The cache expires in mins even I set it to 14 days in slidingExpiration. Thanks in advance!

```
public static List<ReplyDTO> VideoCommentList()
{
     List<ReplyDTO> replyList = new List<ReplyDTO>();
     if (HttpRuntime.Cache["videoComment"] == null)
     {
         HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("videoComment");
         HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("videoComment", replyList, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
     }
     else
     {
         replyList = (List<ReplyDTO>)HttpRuntime.Cache["videoComment"];
     }

     if (replyList.Count > 8)
     {
         replyList = replyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).Take(8).ToList();
     }
     else
     {
         replyList = replyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).ToList();
     }
     return replyList;
}

public static List<ReplyDTO> AddVideoComment(ReplyDTO replyDTO)
{
     List<ReplyDTO> replyList = new List<ReplyDTO>();
     replyList = VideoCommentList();
     replyList.Add(replyDTO);
     HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("videoComment", replyList, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

     if (replyList.Count > 8)
     {
          replyList = replyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).Take(8).ToList();
     }
     else
     {
          replyList = replyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).ToList();
     }
     return replyList;
}
```

Comment: Please read this doc - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.net cache is in-memory, so if your IIS process or application pool recycles it will get clear. You can check following things which can cause recycling of process

- If you modify `web.config`, IIS shutdown the old instance and slowly transfer the traffic to a new instance, in this process in-memory is recycled. **How to check this**: You can detect this situation by checking the [AppDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.isfinalizingforunload.aspx) and logging that during the callback.
- [Application Pool Recycling](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling): There is a configuration in IIS, according to which if IIS process is idle for a specified time, it recycles it. You can check this on server, and increase this time or disable the recycling altogether.
- Every process has limitation on how much memory it can consume, if you are adding too many objects in memory, it will increase the memory consumption of IIS, and in critical time OS will recycle the process.

**EDIT**

In your program you are adding `replyList` item to cache and then doing `.Take()` operation. As `replyList` is reference object, if you modify it, it will get updated in the cache also. So if in your program, if you do `replyList == null` it will update the item in cache.

**So modify your code like this and try**

```
public static List<ReplyDTO> VideoCommentList()
{
    List<ReplyDTO> replyList = new List<ReplyDTO>();
    if (HttpRuntime.Cache["videoComment"] == null)
    {
        //Call to .Remove is not required
        //HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("videoComment");
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("videoComment", replyList, null,
                         Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
    }
    else
    {
        //No need to check count > 8, Take will handle it for you
        replyList = ((List<ReplyDTO>)HttpRuntime.Cache["videoComment"])
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
                        .Take(8).ToList();
    }
    return replyList;
}

public static List<ReplyDTO> AddVideoComment(ReplyDTO replyDTO)
{
    //Read from cache
    List<ReplyDTO> replyList = ((List<ReplyDTO>)HttpRuntime.Cache["videoComment"]);
    if(replyList == null)
        replyList = VideoCommentList();
    replyList.Add(replyDTO);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("videoComment", replyList, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

    //Here you are creating a new list, and not referencing the one in the cache
    return replyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).Take(8).ToList();
}
```

**IMPORTANT SUGGESTION**

If you want to check when and why your object is removed from the cache, you can take help of [CacheItemRemovedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback.aspx) option on the insertion. Using this and [CacheItemRemovedReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedreason.aspx) argument, you can log the reason of object removal from cache. Reasons

1. **Removed** - Your code has removed the item from cache by calling `Insert` or `Remove` method.
2. **Expired** - The item is removed from the cache because it expired.
3. **Underused** - When system run low on memory, it freed up memory by removing item from the cache.
4. **DependencyChanged** - The item is removed from the cache because the cache dependency associated with it changed. (In your case it is not valid)

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Hi Amar, i did not edit any files. I didn't think the IIS pool was recycling because it happened in just mins. This is a new site, therefore, i don't get much traffic for now. The memory shouldn't be a problem. Anything else you can think of? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the App Pool Recycle time? And how did you come to know that the cache get refreshed, you don't have any `CacheItemRemovedCallback`.

Comment: Yes, i did use CacheItemRemovedCallback. I got "2-Removed" back as reason for cache get removed. However, i am supprised object reference is the problem here. Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: @Jack You had placed bounty on this question, who won it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to track down WHY your item is being removed from cache, I'd recommend using a different overload of the `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert` method that allows you to specify a CacheItemRemovedCallback callback function.

[Cache.Insert Method (String, Object, CacheDependency, DateTime, TimeSpan, CacheItemPriority, CacheItemRemovedCallback)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/05kd8d77%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Aside from that your caching code seems good. But once you change your code to specify a callback, log the ejection reason and that will probably give you a better understanding of why your cached item is getting clear.

Like most of the other answers, I suspect that your app is getting recycled/reset for any number of reasons. I think that most apps on a production machine recycle at least once a day, especially in a shared hosting environment.  So I'd guess that your data will stay cached for a day at most.

Comment: too bad, i tried to use callback reason. I get value 0 from it when my cache was gone.

Comment: 0 = Expired in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, but there is no definition for 0 in System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason.  Out of curiosity, have you tried setting the sliding expiration TimeSpan to something like TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) and see if it expires right away still?  Maybe 14 days is too much.

Comment: hi, i have tried the removecallback and logged to database. The reason is 2 - removed. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedreason.aspx : 2 = Removed, but that is not an automatic remove.  It is a manual remove triggered either by you doing a .Remove() call or by calling .Insert() with the same cache key name.  Are you trying to insert many items and by chance attempting to insert an item with the same name?  Try changing you .Insert() calls to .Add(), which fails if key exists, and see if the remove problem goes away.  Not that that is a final solution, but a way to track it down if you cannot debug.

Comment: @Jack you can try my code. I have made some changes which might handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The cache is in-memory and will expire when your application recycles. I'm guessing you're evaluating this on a development machine where either the low amount of traffic, or your file edits causes the application to recycle.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the reply. Actually, this is a new site and in share hosting environment. I barely had any traffic while I was testing this, in addition, I did not edit files during the time.

Comment: humm.. shared hosting you said? Shared hostings uses to shutdown application domains that are being idle for a while, they get reactivated at the first call. Maybe is worth to take a look at how long the AppDomain has been up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056635/programmatically-find-when-the-asp-net-worker-process-and-app-domain-last-starte

Answer (score 0):

Your cache objects can get trimmed due to multiple reasons...

AppDomain recycle. 
Memory pressure.
Crash. 
Use of Web Garden.
Load balancing.
and so on...

This post should clarify a bit more...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praveeny/archive/2006/12/11/asp-net-2-0-cache-objects-get-trimmed-when-you-have-low-available-memory.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the AddVideoComment() method , change the cache item insert lines to:

```
  HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("videoComment", replyList, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromDays(14),CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,null);
```

And in the VideoCommentList() method, use:

```
       if (HttpRuntime.Cache["videoComment"] == null)
        {
            replyList = VideoCommentList(); 
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("videoComment", replyList, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromDays(14),CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,null);
        }
```

No need of using `HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("videoComment");` as `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(` will replace the existing cache item.

Cheers,
*DeveloperConcord*