# Detect IIS website is suspended

Tags: c#, iis, web, detection, suspend

I am currently able to detect whether a IIS Website is started/paused/stopped using the following code:

```
public int GetWebsiteStatus(string machineName, int websiteId)
{
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(
        String.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC/{1}", machineName, websiteId));
    PropertyValueCollection pvc = root.Properties["ServerState"];
    return pvc.Value
    // - 2: Website Started
    // - 4: Website Stopped
    // - 6: Website Paused
}
```

I also want to detect if a Website is suspended or not. If the Website is suspended the method above still returns 2 (which is correct) but not enough for me.

I cannot find any code which do the job for IIS6 and higher.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't return 6 when you pause it?

Comment: What do you mean by "suspended"? You can pause a website in IIS, but do you mean something different?

Comment: @cirrus Pause is a status of the website like Started and Stopped. Suspended is a kind of sub-state of started. If I pause the website I get status 6 so that's OK. But if the website is not used for 20 minutes IIS will suspend the website. If you request the site again it will awake. So it is correct the method above returns 2 because the website is active but suspended.

Comment: @cirrus if the website get suspended, all background threads will be stopped. So if you have a thread which logs each minute the activity of the website itself. this log-thread will not log anymore if the website isn't used for 20 minutes. (Just an example)

Comment: @Clafou. I cannot tag two people to the same comment. Please read comments above to cirrus.

Comment: It might be worth looking into something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056635/programmatically-find-when-the-asp-net-worker-process-and-app-domain-last-starte to determine whether the state is suspended or not? When you receive status 2 you just verify whether the worker processes for the site are up and running or not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, do you mean the App Pool as stopped because of the timeout configuration? This is a different state to the web site remember? Well, certainly, you could change the settings so it doesn't recycle, but you could also try using code like this;

First, add a reference to \Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll, then;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
namespace MSWebAdmin_Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            Site site = serverManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];

            // get the app for this site
            var appName = site.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName;
            ApplicationPool appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[appName];

            Console.WriteLine("Site state is : {0}", site.State);
            Console.WriteLine("App '{0}' state is : {1}", appName, appPool.State);

            if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Stopped)
            {
                // do something because the web site is "suspended"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That code will independantly check the state of your appPool as opposed to your web site. It's possible for the web site to return "started" and the appPool to return "stopped".

See if it works in your case.

Comment: appPool.State only return 'Stopped' if it is completely stopped. So checking the appPool.State will not work because it always return 'Started'. But changing the check a little bit helped me out. I have changed the if on this way `if(appPool.WorkerProcesses.Count == 0) { /*suspended*/ }`. So thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the following code, add your own logic and tidy up of course... but in essence you need to do the following and modify your code as you see fit.

Add the following enum

```
public enum ServerState
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            Starting = 1,
            Started = 2,
            Stopping = 3,
            Stopped = 4,
            Pausing = 5,
            Paused = 6,
            Continuing = 7
        }
```

Search for site and process it...

```
DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + "localhost" + "/W3SVC");
//check each site
foreach (DirectoryEntry site in w3svc.Children)
{
    foreach (var s in site.Properties)
    {
        try
        {
            ServerState state =
                (ServerState)
                Enum.Parse(typeof (ServerState), site.Properties["ServerState"].Value.ToString());

            if (state == ServerState.Paused)
            {
                //Do action
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I hope this is useful for you as well...

http://csharp-tipsandtricks.blogspot.co.uk/2009_12_01_archive.html