# How do I find tell when an AppDomain started?

Tags: .net, appdomain

Similar to [Programmatically find when the ASP.NET worker process and app domain last started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056635/programmatically-find-when-the-asp-net-worker-process-and-app-domain-last-starte) but more general.

How do I find out the start time for an AppDomain?

I've trued something like this:

```
private readonly static DateTime _appDomainStarted = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public static DateTime GetApplicationDomainStartedTimeUTC()
        {
            return _appDomainStarted;
        }
```

But the static only gets created after it's been references once at runtime, so it doesn't work.

Perhaps there's a way to ensure this code automatically gets run when the assembly gets loaded?